# Authenticate and authorize an application with Azure AD to access Azure Service Bus entities

Tags: azure-active-directory

I'm trying to Authenticate and authorize an application with Azure AD to access Azure Service Bus entities but how do I give the Permissions and scope for the Service Bus API.

1. Register your application with an Azure AD
2. Create a client secret
3. How do i give Permissions for read only and scope it to a Azure service bus namespace the my console app ?

I follow this document but it don't explaine how to give premssions and scope to the app.
[Azure service bus authorize  Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/authenticate-application)

Comment: Did you try using RBAC to grant permissions to the service principal?

Answer (score 0):

What I was missing for giving the permission was to go in to the Azure service bus namespace and click on "Access control (IAM)" and then "Add role" add my "Application/Service principal" then the following code work.

```
const fullyQualifiedNamespace = "azure service namespace";

var credential = new ClientSecretCredential("tenet id"
, "application id", "Secreret value");

var client = new ServiceBusClient(fullyQualifiedNamespace, credential);
const receiver = client.createReceiver("the queue name");
const myMessages = await receiver.peekMessages(10);
myMessages.forEach(r => {    
    console.log(r.body)
})
```